# Wordpress is ruining links to user profiles...?

Tags: html, links, seo

I run a website that deals in reviews and as part of my SEO process I add a link to every authors archive of articles at the bottom of each new piece.

Recently this has broken. When visiting it is adding the slug of the article into a link that I specifically added, breaking it.

For illustration, it is adding this

https://thegeekshow.co.uk/murder-obsession-1981-review/graham.williamson/

to this, every single time

https://thegeekshow.co.uk/graham.williamson/

Additionally, any and all links to writer profiles are broken. I'm really our of my depth here. Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: is thegeekshow.co.uk your website? It's not clear what's being added, is it `graham.williamson` or the entire URL or something I've missed? It's not very clear, use the edit link to make your question as unambiguous and clear as possible, and make sure it contains everything needed to figure out a solution. This isn't a discussion forum so back and forth will greatly reduce the chances of an answer

Comment: also there's no code in your question or information about how your author profiles are added, any plugins that are used, etc. The issue you're describing is not something WP does out of the box, additional code would need to be added to do this. Anything that changes post permalinks or rewrite rules would also be helpful to know. It looks like author archive links are being 302' redirected to `/last-published-post-slug/author-slug` but there's not enough information and no code to debug. The link you added is not being changed, but people who visit it are being redirected